# ruby on rails simple_format adding <br> to bold and italic list items

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email-templates

Whenever we have a list item that starts with bold or italic text and then it has normal text, a 
 appears just in front of the `<strong>` or `<italic>` tag. This happens only if there's a mixture of font-styles. It appears in every single email client.

**HTML**

```
<ul><li><strong>bold</strong></li><li><strong>bold </strong>and normal</li><li>normal and <strong>bold</strong></li><li><em>italic</em><strong> </strong>and normal</li><li>normal and <em>italic</em></li><li><strong>bold </strong>and <em>italic</em></li><li><strong><em>bold-italic</em></strong></li></ul>
```

**How it appears in every email client**

[image: Email screenshot]

This is the code when I inspect the email

[image: markup screenshot]

Any suggestions why is that happening?

Comment: Follow this guideline and improve your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Can you share the original string passed through simple_format ?

Comment: Yep. This is the string from the second screenshot - "<ul><li><strong>bold </strong>and normal</li></ul>"

Comment: By the way, the string is stored in database

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a `simple_format` issue. From what I'm seeing it is due to Chrome html source autocorect.

If you notice, this happens every two `<li>` tag.

This is because `simple_format` convert every new line into a `<br>` tag which is not permitted inside a `<ul>`. So Chrome corrects that for you and tries to put in the first allowed spot. In your case, inside the next `<li>` tag.

To be sure, try outputting the result of `simple_format(your_text)` in the rails console. You should see what the problem is.

#### Workaround (kind of)

Try to remove all the `\n` between the `<ul>` tag and put into a single line, like this:

```
<ul><li>First</li><li>Second</li><li>Third</li></ul>
```

Comment: Sorry, I gave too little info in the description. Just edited my question. The thing is that this happens in every single email client. So I don't think is Chrome doing that. Also, the markup already looks the same way as the one you posted.